# Facebook logout Windows Phone Application without opening WebBrowser

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, logout

I am trying to develop a Windows Phone 7 application using Facebook login and logout operations. I found Facebook SDK and used it in order to carry out login, by opening WebBrowser. The user enters credentials to this browser and logs in successfully. Moreover, I managed to login the user without using any SDK, just using http requests, like the SDK actually does. However, I want to logout users without using any WebBrowser, but just clicking a button for example. There are so many solutions in the web suggesting that I should open web browser and navigate it to a certain URL in order to logout. However, this is not what I want. I think there should be a way to logout by clearing cookies, which I dont exactly know how to do, or any other that you suggest. Some part of my code below:

```
    private static String appID = "";
    private static String appSecret = "";

    public static void login(String[] permissions)
    {
        try
        {
            permissionArray = permissions;

            popup = new Popup();
            popup.Height = 480;
            popup.Width = 480;
            popup.VerticalOffset = 100;
            FacebookLoginUserControl control = new FacebookLoginUserControl();
            control.facebookWebBrowser.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(webBrowser_Loaded);
            control.facebookWebBrowser.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(webBrowser_Navigated);

            popup.Child = control;
            popup.IsOpen = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //handle
        }
    }

    private static void webBrowser_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
        String loginUrl = GetFacebookLoginUrl();
        wb.Navigate(new Uri(loginUrl));
    }

    private static String GetFacebookLoginUrl()
    {
        String permissionString = String.Empty;
        if (permissionArray.Length > 0)
            permissionString = String.Join(",", permissionArray);

        var uriParams = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                    {"client_id", appID},
                    {"response_type", "token"},
                    {"scope", permissionString},
                    {"redirect_uri", "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"},
                    {"display", "touch"}
                };
        StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var current in uriParams)
        {
            if (urlBuilder.Length > 0)
            {
                urlBuilder.Append("&");
            }
            var encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(current.Value);
            urlBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}={1}", current.Key, encoded);
        }
        var loginUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" + urlBuilder.ToString();

        return loginUrl;
    }

    private static void webBrowser_Navigated(Object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Uri.Fragment)) return;
        if (e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(e.Uri.Fragment, "") == "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")
        {
            string text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Uri.Fragment).TrimStart('#');
            var pairs = text.Split('&');
            foreach (var pair in pairs)
            {
                var kvp = pair.Split('=');
                if (kvp.Length == 2)
                {
                    if (kvp[0] == "access_token")
                    {
                        accessToken = kvp[1];
                        MessageBox.Show("Access granted");
                        RequestUserProfile();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to authenticate");
            }
            popup.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    private static void RequestUserProfile()
    {
        var profileUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(accessToken));
        request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(profileUrl));
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.BeginGetResponse(result =>
        {
            try
            {
                var resp = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result);
                using (var strm = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strm);
                    var responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //
            }
        }, request);
    }
```

Any Ideas to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What's actually so spooky in using webBrowser? If you programmatically create a WebBrowser object, it won't be visible, unless you'd add it somewhere on form/page. If you want to clear cookies for Facebook, the solution will be something like that:

```
// Can be invoked from your button_click event
 public void TryLogout()
        {
            webBrowser = new WebBrowser();

            Uri uri = new Uri("http://m.facebook.com/home.php?r", UriKind.Absolute);
            webBrowser.LoadCompleted += new LoadCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser_TryLogoutLoadCompleted);
            webBrowser.Navigate(uri);
        }
```

And then:

```
private void webBrowser_TryLogoutLoadCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var cookies = webBrowser.GetCookies();

                foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
                {
                    if (cookie.Domain.Contains("m.facebook.com"))
                    {
                        cookie.Discard = true;
                        cookie.Expired = true;
                    }
                }
            // we've just cleaned up cookies

            }
            finally
            {
                webBrowser.LoadCompleted -= webBrowser_TryLogoutLoadCompleted;
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.

[GetCookies method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowserextensions.getcookies%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: The problem is that WebBrowser control has no method like GetCookies in Windows Phone 7.

Comment: It has. Have you added reference to System.Net?

Comment: It is already added. Yes, System.Net has methods and classes about cookies but GetCookies method that you use above must be belong to WebBrowser class, which is in the namespace of 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls'

Comment: Actually it's in **Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserExtensions** class, but if you add 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls' namespace it should work. Lemme think a bit...

Comment: Strange. The only reason for this, that I could ever imagine, is that you're working with Windows Phone 7.0 as target OS version. As I can see, the method is available on OS-s: Windows Phone OS
Supported in: 8.0, 7.1. Is this true? You can see it at RightClick at Project->Application->Target OS version

Comment: Yes, it is Windows Phone 7.0, and unfortunately I have to use 7.0 due to some compatibility issues. Any solution for it??

Comment: No, I think this one will only for 7.1 & higher. Perhaps someone else would answer you a solution for 7.0. You can also try to check the **webRequest.CookieContainer.GetCookies(uri)** method for WebRequest, but I'm not sure about it. Good luck.