# Are cookies stored per App?

Tags: cookies, browser, windows-phone

Are cookies in Windows Phone stored on a per-App basis? 
And if yes: how can I clear the cookies which are stored by an App (given I control the source code of this App)?

And phrased from a slightly different angle: If I clear the history in the phone's Internet Explorer are cookies in Apps (that embed the web browser control) deleted, too?

Answer (score 1):

> Are cookies in Windows Phone stored on a per-App basis?

Yes, they are stored on a per-app basis. That means you can be logged with one Facebook account in IE, another one in App X and a third one in App Y.

> How can I clear the cookies which are stored by an App

As far as I know, there is no easy way to do this. Maybe you should try that:

- [Clearing Cookies on Windows Phone 7](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/120763/Clearing-Cookies-on-Windows-Phone-7-or-How-to-Log)
- [Facebook logout Windows Phone Application without opening WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551662/facebook-logout-windows-phone-application-without-opening-webbrowser)

> If I clear the history in the phone's Internet Explorer are cookies in
>   Apps (that embed the web browser control) deleted, too?

No, cookies from IE are different from cookies stored by the `WebBrowser` control.

Comment: Unfortunately `WebBrowser.GetCookies()` returns a read-only cookie collection. So solution suggested in the linked questions doesn't work. But thanks for the other infos.